# How to get Twilio's RequestValidator to work

Tags: python, django, twilio

I'm not sure why this doesn't work.  I have been looking at Twilio's documentation [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/how-to-secure-your-django-project-by-validating-incoming-twilio-requests), and I tried just making it a function call, but that didn't work, so I put it directly in my view, and it still didn't work.  It always returns 403.

I have verified that my auth token is the same as what is on Twilio as well.

```
from braces.views import CsrfExemptMixin
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseForbidden
from twilio.util import RequestValidator
from secretphone.settings import TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN


class SMSWebhook(CsrfExemptMixin, View):
    def post(self, request):
        validator = RequestValidator(TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN)
        request_valid = validator.validate(
            request.build_absolute_uri(),
            request.POST,
            request.META.get('HTTP_X_TWILIO_SIGNATURE', '')
        )

        if not request_valid:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

Comment: What URI is being generated by `request.build_absolute_uri()`? From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/http/request/#HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri) it looks as though it might come out as schemaless.

Comment: I kept looking at it, and it appeared to be the correct URL, but I guess using ngrok somehow ends up stripping the https off of the url.  It came out as http only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So that nobody has the same problem I did, and no answer, apparently ngrok's https URL does not get passed through to django.  My problem was that my webhook was passed using ngrok's https link, but when it got to my app, it changed to an http link.  My guess is that `request.build_absolute_uri()` gets the protocol from django(webserver) itself, which uses http as the protocol.

So anyone having this problem while using ngrok, make sure you are not using the https link.

Comment: I had the same problem (in C#). I had to rewrite the request URI to use show https, even though it came through ngrok as http.